# How can I list all databases and all tables of my databases with a final "Attach" and list total row of each table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I did this. But unfortunately that return all in many table. I want to return all in one unique table. Maybe using "UNION" but I don't know the way to do.

This is my code:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'select ''?''AS "DataBase", s.name, t.name AS "Tables",max(si.rows) as "Rows Line"
 from [?].sys.tables t inner join [?].sys.schemas s 
 on t.schema_id = s.schema_id  
 inner join [?].sys.partitions si on t.object_id  = si.object_id
 where t.name like "%ATTACH" group by s.name,t.name'`
```

Comment: thx for editing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found finally a solution.i just used a Stored Procedures for having the result i was looking for.So decided to post the answer here maybe that will help someone else.

```
DECLARE @banco_nome nvarchar(MAX), @tabela_nome nvarchar(MAX)

DECLARE @banco_cursor CURSOR  
DECLARE @sqlstatement nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @count_sql nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @total int

DECLARE @RegistrosFotograficos TABLE
(
  DatabaseName nvarchar(max),
  TableName nvarchar(max),
  Total int
)

SET @banco_cursor = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
    SELECT name FROM sys.databases

OPEN @banco_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @banco_cursor INTO @banco_nome
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sqlstatement = 'DECLARE tabela_cursor CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ' + @banco_nome + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE'' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE ''%ATTACH'' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstatement

    OPEN tabela_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM tabela_cursor INTO @tabela_nome
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @count_sql = 'USE ' + @banco_nome + '; SELECT @total=COUNT(1) FROM ' + @tabela_nome;
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @count_sql, N'@total int OUTPUT', @total=@total OUTPUT

        INSERT INTO @RegistrosFotograficos (DatabaseName, TableName, Total) VALUES (@banco_nome, @tabela_nome, @total);

        FETCH NEXT FROM tabela_cursor INTO @tabela_nome
    END
    CLOSE tabela_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE tabela_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM @banco_cursor INTO @banco_nome
END
CLOSE @banco_cursor;
DEALLOCATE @banco_cursor;

SELECT * FROM @RegistrosFotograficos
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in a single query.

You could query the sys.databases table to get a temporary table of all your databases, and then run a dynamic query on each database to store the results of the query in your question all in another temporary table.

Then at the end, you just select all rows from the last temporary table.

Comment: i tried to understand what u told but i still with many question...could u please show me hjow to do,creating a script  and let just some comments to me understand it.

Comment: No, sorry I don't have a script handy for this.   Break it down into small steps and try each one, and ask a new question if you have a specific problem with one.

Comment: okay thx for replying @Tab Alleman. I will try to find a way to get out of this trouble mind hahahah...

Answer (score 0):

This will list all the tables in a given database and the number of rows in each. Notice the results are in a table named #results:

```
set nocount on

declare @curtable sysname
declare @prevtable sysname
declare @curcount int
declare @tsql varchar(500)

if object_ID('tempdb..#curtables','U') is not null
    drop table #curtables

select name  into #curtables 
from sys.objects 
where type='U' 
order by 1

if object_id('tempdb..#results','U') is not null
    drop table #results 

create table #results(name sysname,numrows int)

select top 1 @curtable=name from #curtables order by name
while (1=1)
begin

    set @tsql = 'select '''+quotename(@curtable) +''',count(*) numrows  from '+quotename(@curtable)
    print @tsql
    insert into #results
    exec (@tsql)
    set @prevtable= @curtable 
    select top 1 @curtable = name 
    from #curtables 
    where name > @prevtable 
    order by name
    if   @curtable=@prevtable
        break
```

end